# One-past-end-of-object pointers

Tags: c++, c

I know that pointer comparisons are only defined if the two pointers
point somewhere "into" the storage allocated to the same object, or if
they are NULL, or one-past the end of the object as long as it isn't
dereferenced.

I use "object" in the standard 'C' sense.

Is there some special dispensation given to comparing two pointers
that are -each- one past the end of the object as opposed to
comparing a one-past-end pointer and an pointer expression derived
referencing the actual object. Given the following definitions:

```
 char arr[100];
 char *pend = &arr[99];
 char *pa = pend+1;
 char *pb = pend+1;
```

is the comparison `pa == pb` guaranteed to be meaningful or does it
invoke UB because -neither- pa nor pb point into arr.

In otherwords, from the standard's point of view, is there a
semantic difference between comparing pa and pb and comparing,
say, pa and `&arr[99]+1` ?
it might seem obvious but :)

Comment: It's not only valid, it's the standard way of handling iterators (see e.g. [`std::end`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end)). And as long as the pointers are *related* (for example, both pointing to the same array, or come from the same base pointer (like `pend` in your case)) then it's not UB.

Comment: it is guaranteed as long they point both 1 past the SAME object. But if so, it is. (regarding to C as my knowledge about the c++ part isn't covering this.)

Comment: `==` is at most unspecified, never undefined, in C. It would be nice if the standard used the word "unspecified"; it doesn't, but the words it does use suggest that it is unspecified. If one of the pointers involved is way out (more-than-one past) or dangling, then it is the operand itself that causes the undefined behavior, not `==`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a good example of why you shouldn't tag your questions both as C and as C++:

For C, this is covered by the standard.

> **6.5.9 Equality operators**
>
> 6 Two pointers compare equal if and only if both are null pointers, both are pointers to the same object (including a pointer to an object and a subobject at its beginning) or function, **both are pointers to one past the last element of the same array object**, or one is a pointer to one past the end of one array object and the other is a pointer to the start of a different array object that happens to immediately follow the first array object in the address space.

For C++, it is not so clear:

> **5.10 Equality operators [expr.eq]**
>
> 1 The `==` (equal to) and the `!=` (not equal to) operators have the same semantic restrictions, conversions, and result type as the relational operators except for their lower precedence and truth-value result. [ *Note:* `a<b == c<d` is `true` whenever `a<b` and `c<d` have the same truth-value. -- *end note* ] Pointers of the same type (after pointer conversions) can be compared for equality. Two pointers of the same type compare equal if and only if they are both null, both point to the same function, **or both represent the same address (3.9.2)**.

Technically, I don't see where the standard requires that two past-the-end pointers represent the same address. I can find where the standard requires that an object has an address, and the `&` operator returns that specific address (so taking the address twice produces the same pointer value), but a past-the-end pointer does not point to an object, so that does not apply. They might be different, so long as subtracting works to get back to the same array base.

In practice, though, you won't have to worry about that, and it will work in C++ just as well as in C.

*Update:* per JohnB's answer and the comments there, the C++ standard may have intended to require this much more explicitly, but it does require it indirectly nonetheless.

Comment: "They might be different, so long as subtracting works to get back to the same array base" -- which implies that they can't be different.

Comment: @JimBalter No, it doesn't. `a - 1 == b - 1` does not generally imply `a == b`. It's already not true for numeric types (either because of integer overflow, or because of floating point loss of precision), and the standard doesn't require it anywhere for pointer types either.

Comment: You're confused. We're not talking about floating loss of precision and integer overflow is only relevant because it's UB. For pointers, the inference holds. See JohnB's answer.

Comment: @JimBalter The only logic I could possibly think of is "it works like that for all types, so it works like that for pointer types too", which is why I attempted to show it doesn't work like that for all types. If that isn't the argument you were making, then what is your argument? On what basis can you make that claim?

Comment: Perhaps you missed where I said to see JohnB's answer. See also  Joachim Pileborg's comment above about std::end. g'nite.

Comment: @JimBalter I didn't miss that, which is why I commented on that answer too. That answer doesn't contradict anything I said or suggested.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, that's guaranteed only for *forward iterators*:

> **24.2.5 Forward iterators**
>
> A class or pointer type X satisfies the requirements of a forward iterator if
>   [...] objects of type X offer the multi-pass guarantee, described below.
>   [...]
>
> The domain of == for forward iterators is that of iterators over the
>   same underlying sequence. [...]
>
> Two
>   dereferenceable iterators a and b of type X offer the multi-pass
>   guarantee if:
>
> — a == b implies ++a == ++b and [...]

From 24.4.1 (specialization of `iterator_traits` for pointers) it follows that pointers are random access iterators and thus, forward iterators.

Alternatively, but maybe less convincing, for arrays you can implicitly infer that `(p+1) == (q+1)` if both `p` and `q` point to the last element of the array, from the wording of the following:

> **5.7 Additive operators**
>   [...]
>   Moreover, if the expression P points to the last element of an array
>   object, the expression (P)+1 points one past the last element of the
>   array object, and if the expression Q points one past the last element
>   of an array object, the expression (Q)-1 points to the last element of
>   the array object.

This implicitly assumes that there is a single well-defined address representing "one past the last element". (Arrays are linear, "one past the last element" includes the fiction that the linear thing *array* is extended, and the natural extension of a linear thing is, again, linear, so there can be only one thing *"one past the last element"*. Note the distinction the standard makes between "one past the last element" and simply "past the last element" elsewhere.)

Comment: Suppose there are two possible addresses, that behave identically when subtracting: `a != b`, but `a - 1 == b - 1`. Your answer doesn't explain why one-past-the-last-element can't sometimes return `a`, yet sometimes return `b`. Yes, an implementation that would do so would be somewhat silly, but when we're talking about what the standard strictly requires, we have to keep such silly implementations in mind.

Comment: Suppose 1 == 2. Oh, wait, that isn't possible either.

Comment: @JimBalter I'll believe it's not possible once I see proof that it's not possible. I haven't seen such proof yet. Until I see such proof, I only consider it very unlikely, not impossible. This is the last comment I'm making to you.

Comment: @hvd: My argument is that "one-past-the-last-element" must be a well-defined value, as otherwise it does not make sense to give it a name.

Comment: @JohnB But in my hypothetical implementation, "you could just write "(P)+1 points to anywhere outside the array" wouldn't be true: (P)+1 (where P points to the last element of the array preceding a/b) would *have* to return either `a` or `b`, it couldn't just return some garbage value.

Comment: @hvd I don't care what you will or won't believe. The proof is implicit in what has been written here ... I'm sorry that you can't see that.

Comment: @JohnB FWIW, if there is any explicit claim that pointer types are valid forward iterators, then your quote about forward iterators does prove my answer wrong: forward iterators do explicitly guarantee what the OP is asking for.

Comment: @hvd Is that some sort of joke? pointers are random-access iterators and all random-access iterators are forward iterators.

Comment: And that pointers are random access iterators follows from the specialization of `iterator_traits` for pointers, given in 24.4.1

Comment: "if there is any explicit claim" -- wrong criterion. Much of what is true is implicit. This certainly includes the impossibility of "two possible addresses, that behave identically when subtracting: a != b, but a - 1 == b - 1". *addresses* are even more concrete than pointers.

Comment: @JohnB Thanks. The reason I asked is that the logic *should* work the other way around: the logic should be that pointer types match the requirements of random access iterators, therefore they are random access iterators. But if that doesn't work, and there is an explicit claim that they are random access iterators, it does still follow from that that they match the requirements of random access iterators, and one of the requirements of random access iterators is what the OP asks about.